# HTMLAudioElement exclusively intercepts all keyboard events - how to override?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, keyboard-events

I have a very simple media player web-page with `audio` tag. It's necessary to provide a user with keyboard shortcuts, which would work consistently throughout the page, irrespective to what element is currently focused.

Unfortunately, when the audio element has a focus, it intercepts all keyboard events, no matter which event handlers are assigned. Just a side-note: the focus is not even highlighted until a user presses any key, as it's in my environment Windows 11/Chrome-based browser, so the default usability is very pour.

I have tried both `document.addEventListener` and `window.addEventListener` for "keydown" with capture phase on (last parameter is true) and bubble phase (false). In any case the events are swallowed by the audio. "keypress" doesn't survive either.

[image]

If I click somewhere outside the audio, the keyboard events start working as expected.

How to take global control over keyboard events and disable keyboard events trap inside the audio-element? Current default implementation of keyboard events in the audio looks like an overkill and spoils UI interactions for entire page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onPlay`, `onSeeked`, and `onVolumeChange` events to blur focus off the audio player after a default button has been clicked (or the audio seeked) and ensure your keyboard shortcuts work.  For example:

```html
<audio onPlay="blurAudioPlayer()" controls>
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/858/outfoxing.mp3" />
</audio>

...
```

```js
const blurAudioPlayer = () => {
  const audioElement = document.querySelector('audio');
  if (audioElement === null || audioElement === undefined) return;
  audioElement.blur();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a useful workaround.